# How to extract command output from interactive shell?

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract a string command output, I want to use a regex to get a  string from the whole output, specifically the middle string between two separators:

This is a shell command output and I'm printin a string `__SEPARATOR__` the first has simple quotes and the last no quotes:

```
ls -l && echo '__SEPARATOR__'\r\ntotal 36\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 3 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 27 09:26 \x1b[0m\x1b[01;34mDesktop\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mDocuments\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mDownloads\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mMusic\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mPictures\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mPublic\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 3 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:11 \x1b[01;34msnap\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mTemplates\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mVideos\x1b[0m\r\n__SEPARATOR__\r\nVMlinux2@ubuntu:~$
```

My regex:

```
'__SEPARATOR__'(.*)__SEPARATOR__
```

So I'm trying to get the middle string between those separators

```
regex = r"'__SEPARATOR__'(.*)__SEPARATOR__"
text = re.search(regex, output).group(1)
print(text)
```

But I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I tried with simple texts like:

```
I'm want to get the '__SEPARATOR__' middle text __SEPARATOR__ from this text
```

And it works well, also I tried removing break lines and all others but same error.

What I'm doing wrong? or which approach can I take for this issue?

Comment: That's the command output? It looks more like the command itself.

Comment: Have you tried verifying that `output` is exactly what you think it is? Can you show the code that sets it?

Comment: Your regexp has two underscores before and after `SEPARATOR`, but the output only has a single underscore.

Comment: Yes, sorry the output and the regex has two undercores, my bad editing..

Comment: But still same error

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the problem is that the "." symbol does not match lines break. What you need to do is `or` this with the possible line breaks you could get. A (somewhat) complete solution would be something like:

```py
>>> regex = r"'__SEPARATOR__'((.|\r|\n|\r\n|\n\r)*)__SEPARATOR__"
>>> mo = re.search(regex, output)
>>> mo.group(1)
'\r\ntotal 36\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 3 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 27 09:26 \x1b[0m\x1b[01;34mDesktop\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mDocuments\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mDownloads\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mMusic\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mPictures\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mPublic\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 3 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:11 \x1b[01;34msnap\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mTemplates\x1b[0m\r\ndrwxr-xr-x 2 VMlinux2 VMlinux2 4096 Sep 26 13:10 \x1b[01;34mVideos\x1b[0m\r\n'
```